# Can't call function from other class

Tags: swift, function, class, sprite-kit, uilabel

So I am trying to call a function from my score class that will add one to the score:

```
Score.addOneToScore(1)
```

but I end up getting this error:

> cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Score'

I'm pretty sure i've overlooked something but i can't seem to see it.

Here is my score class:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit


class Score: SKLabelNode {

var number = 0

init (num: Int) {

    super.init()

    fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    fontName = "Helvetica"
    fontSize = 75.0


    number = num
    text = "\(num)"

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func addOneToScore() {

    number++
    text = "\(number)"

  }

}
```

Comment: `func addOneToScore()` does not take any arguments in definition. but you are passing it 1?

Comment: if i take the one out and just call it without it then it just gives me another error saying it is missing argument for parameter #1 in call which i can't really figure out why either.

Comment: @Astrum Because you are using it like you shouldn't (like it's a static function). addOneToScore() is an instance method. Look at Greg's answer to see how you should use your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few mistake you make:
You are trying to call
addOneToScore() as a class (static) function but it's an instance one, and you are passing the parameter but the function doesn't take one, try this:

```
let score = Score(num: 0) // Initialise score with the value of 1
score.addOneToScore() // add one to the score
print("\(score.number)") // print the value (1)
```

Comment: yeah that fixed it but for some reason it doesn't add to the score

Comment: You should add an constant to the class level where you need it: let score = Score(num: 0) (add this line just after class 'your class name') and call just score.addOneToScore() where you need it.

Comment: Your answer worked, but it doesn't seem to change the score label to display the number 1 it just keeps showing 0